# .NET SQL Login & further action

Tags: sql, .net, authentication

i already made a few login scripts for .NET and the belonging SQL-Server.

At the moment i'm wondering how you proceed, when the user has successfully logged in.

I mean for example:
A user logs in, it was successful, then you may set an id in the program:
loggedinuser = 1 'means the id from the database of the user.

But what if someone changes that value, with some malicous program?

That would be called session hijacking correct?

How to proceed then?

Hope you could understand what im trying to explain.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing that value in a cookie or something else front-end?

Typically, you never expose your database primary keys to the user for any reason (it's a good rule of thumb not only for user IDs but for any kind of sequential IDs stored in your database). There are frameworks out there which already handle all of these security considerations for you behind the scenes, but granted that you are already building something homegrown, here are two ways you can prevent session hijacking...

1) You can encrypt the user ID before sending it into the front-end. That way, the user only sees a string of nonsense characters and will not be able to change anything.

2) Another (better) way is to use a session token. This could be a GUID, or another fully random number, which would be the only thing that would be sent to the user. On your backend, this token would map to a "session" which would contain the User ID, among other things. The data would only be available on the server and the user would never know what is stored in the session.

There are many other ways of handling this, but the above two are the most common and straightforward.

However, the best way is to use an established framework (such as ASP.NET Membership) which already takes care of all of these concerns for you. Doing it yourself will always introduce bugs and leave niche cases very easy to miss.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your time. The problem is, trat i am bound to a setup like: getting data via php through web request from .net Application. Etc.. I cant change it :/.. I think the recommended thing for me is, to take the session id thingy,  on successful login, the user client receives the Session id and yeah, then i'll send the data authenticating through this.

Comment: Ps: Now i need to find a way to generate that session id with an algorythm that wont get Double entries that fast and which will make it difficult to hijack an exisiting one, for example through big strings?

Comment: You can use a GUID. They are practically guaranteed to be unique and are large enough to be virtually impossible to guess or pick randomly. Guid.NewGuid() in C# or NEWID() in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Is there a method in php to create it? So that the user on the frontend cant hack/crack it how its generated (or something like that). My thought is to set a new session id, received from Server to be used by the client. (On successful login). And i need to manage it anyhow that old guids expire.

Comment: PHP has the uniqid function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), although many are saying that it is not ideal for security purposes. It may or may not be sufficient for what you are building, though. If you think you might need even more security, consider searching online for better ways to generate a UUID in PHP, or hashing the result of uniqid(). Or, possibly, create an algorithm to generate your own unique string. Or ideally, just use the database to create it.

Comment: For expiration, just add a clause into your SQL query that checks the token to check a timestamp value as well. For example, something like "SELECT s.internal_session_id FROM sessions s WHERE s.external_guid = @ExternalGuidPassedAsAParameter *and s.timestamp >= DATEADD(minute, -90, GETDATE())*"

Comment: Okay i managed to create a good unique session id and to send it to the client, as well i have a timestamp in the database and some other things. When the user does any action with other scripts ill just send the sessionid, Check whether its still active and with that session id i know which User wann to Do something, so I van Check whether he is able to. Ps: a really big thank you, to you! :)

Comment: @mademyday Great! Let me know if you have any other questions related to this. If not, and my answer helped, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: I think there will be more coming,  when i did some more work.

Comment: Im currently thinking how to proceed if a login (session id) expired. on every Action of a user (in differrent scripts), i check if the given session id exists and whether its still active or already expired. My thought here is, to tell the user to relogin and either to set a whole New session id or refresh the timestamp of the old one. My fear there is, that Hackers could mal-use this Function to make Infinite time session ids. Thanks ;)!

Comment: @mademyday I'd say you most definitely want to have sliding expiration (extend the session on every hit). While that has some potential for abuse, this is how virtually all sites work in this day and age. Having the session expire on a user while they're using your web-app will almost guarantee very annoyed users. However, it really depends on the nature of your app, but I'd say I never seen something where the session can just expire in the middle of someone using your site. There is some potential for abuse, although I can't think of what would be accomplished by exploiting that...

Comment: @mademyday I can do the same thing on any other site (Amazon, etc.)... Just auto-refresh the page every 5 minutes and essentially keep my session open forever.

Comment: Okay your right with that argument, that the users will be annoyed on relogging many times^^.. Right now im thinking about killing the old Logins from one User Who has logged in. That means, if a user loggs in, it'll delete the old sessions of the user. That kinda cleans up the database. If i would make a delete/logout the attacker could more easily manipulate the logout. Like this only the login Script knows what to Do etc.

Comment: Sounds about right. If my answer and this discussion helped you, please remember to mark it as such.